# Does anyone know why when we add vinegar to rice its texture changes? I would like to understand "chemically" what happens

Tags: rice, vinegar

I'm trying to improve my brown rice recipe, and although I put some vinegar in it, I still don't understand how it works. Does it make the rice stickier or looser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acids lower the pH, making amylase less effective in breaking down starch into sugar. I believe with rice it helps remove the starch from the rice as well, so adding vinegar to rice will make it less sticky. Rinsing the rice well before cooking will also make it less sticky (because you're rinsing off the starch).